# Definite article vs indefinite article vs no article

Tags: articles

It is said that when we are referring to a noun for the first time then we use an indefinite article.

For example,

> "I disagree with **the** thesis written by Guya Jones.

Here *thesis* is mentioned for the first time then why is 'the' used instead of 'a'?

Take another example,

> There is a book in my bag.

Here 'a' sounds perfectly OK.

Why is the article 'the' used in the former sentence?

Comment: Possible duplicates are: [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a), [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251149/is-there-any-difference-in-meaning-among-the-definite-the-indefinite-and-zero-a) and [many other questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=definite+indefinite+article) on here.

Comment: You use the definite article when you immediately specify which instance of *noun* you are talking about--here, the thesis **written by Guya Jones**.

Comment: @StoneyB -- according to this reasoning why can't we use 'the'in the latter example ? I am confused like hell.

Comment: Intuitively I use all the articles correctly but when I start justifying it with the rules the grammar book mentions then I just fumble up. Can I say that all articles cannot be justified by those oversimplified rules which every grammar book mentions ? Plz guide me. Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell us where you found your rules, and why "_the thesis_ written" is ideal? You mention "indefinite article" then use the definite article in _the thesis_. There could be reasons to refer to _a thesis_ or to _the thesis_, depending on what comes before.The second time I tell you "When I went to _a mountain_ in Colorado, it was great," I can still use the indefinite article.

Comment: @Yosef : go to this link http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380395/why-does-the-speaker-use-the-indefinite-article-in-this-is-the-last-time-you-ar

Comment: Read all the comments by @Clare. He says that 'the' can be used even if it's being used for the first time .

Comment: Clare is clear, but your question says use the indefinite while your example uses the definite article _the_.

Comment: Presumably, Guya Jones, whoever he is,  is famous for a specific thesis. The speaker and the listener understand *which* thesis is being referred to, it's **the** one written by Jones. Maybe Jones has written several theses, but the speaker is implying there is only one specific thesis that is relevant  at this point.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A : Take this example -- I'm talking to X over the phone. X says "Why are you speaking so slow?" Me: "Because my parents are around here. Okay, wait, I'm going to 'the' lobby".   Here why did I use 'the' before lobby when I know for a fact that X doesn't know which lobby I'm referring to ?

Comment: Because in all likelihood there is only ever one lobby in any given hotel, guest house or very large house. So even if the speaker mentions it the first time, the listener understands what is being referred to. Moreover, I've probably seen the speaker's house so I know exactly which lobby the speaker is talking about. It's very unlikely that any building has more than one lobby.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A :    I request you to go through this link & read Clare's answer. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380395/why-does-the-speaker-use-the-indefinite-article-in-this-is-the-last-time-you-ar  Plz tell me what is the difference between definite noun and an indefinite noun which is specific. How a non native English speaker like me distinguish between the two. If possible, clarify it with an example.

Comment: You need to formulate a new question, comments are not meant for discussions. I understand what she's talking about (Clare is the name of a woman), and I think she explained it better than I could. I wouldn't get so stressed out about when and where to use the definite article, there are more important things you should study to improve your level of English. See my edit.

Comment: I also upvoted StoneyB's answer. The man is perhaps one of the most erudite users on the site, but don't tell him I told you that. ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a)

Answer (score 1):

These uses involve the difference between *predicates* and *modifiers*.

- A **predicate** is some 'new' fact your sentence asserts about its subject. The entire assertion, including both subject and predicate, is called a 'predication'.)

  In your *There is a book in my bag* is a sort of paraphrase of the predication

  > A book is in my bag.

  *A book*, designating some indefinite (unspecified) book, is the subject of the sentence, and *(is) in my bag* is the predicate. This predication does not specify what book you are talking about, it only asserts the presence of some indefinite (unspecified) book in your bag.

  In subsequent sentences, however, you may treat this book as definite (specified)—

  > The book in my bag is red.

  Now *in my bag* is no longer a predicate but . . .
- A **modifier**. A modifier is something 'presupposed' about its head, the noun it modifies; it's an 'old' fact.

  And if the modifier identifies its head sufficiently for your hearer to know exactly which instance of 'noun' you are talking about, the noun phrase is definite (specified) and may take the definite article, *even if 'noun' has not been mentioned previously.

Note, however, that you are not *required* to treat a modified noun as definite. You use the definite article to signal your hearer or reader that you are speaking of a specific instance of 'noun' which you expect her to be familiar with and to recognize.

Comment: I was looking up the definition of indefinite article and the definition reads like this : "The indefinite article is used when 'the' noun is....." Could you tell me why 'the' was used and if I use 'a' instead then what will be the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

We all know articles are very difficult for language learners because there are so many exceptions.  But I find the following general rules go a long way to cover many of the uses.  For the question that was submitted, I think Rule 2 gives an idea of why 'the' was used:

**Rule 1:** Indefinite articles (a, an) are used for previously unknown nouns that are being introduced into a dialogue or story and definite articles are used for nouns that have already been introduced (or are already known or are assumed to be known at the point of introduction to the conversation).

For example:  I saw a cat. The cat was sitting on a fence. The fence was painted brown. The cat jumped off the fence when it saw a mouse. The mouse ran into a hole when it saw the cat so the cat didn't catch the mouse.

**Rule 2:**  The definite article 'the' is used when something is unique or, in other words, there is only one of that object.

For example:  The sun, the president, the queen of England, the capital city, and the moon

It is used for objects that are well known by many or most people, but it is true even when the hearer may not know the object: 
A:Who's he?
B:He's the president of Korea. She's the CFO. He's the mayor.

This can be contrasted with:
A: Who's she?
B: She's a member of parliament. She's an accountant. He's an alderman.

This uniqueness can come by association: 
A car crashed into a tree. The driver was seriously injured.

**Rule 3:** When we are speaking of a noun in general we usually leave the article out, and, if it is countable, use the plural form.*

For Example: I like cookies. This is talking about cookies in general.
However, if I say 'I like the chocolate chip cookies.' I am talking about specific cookies.

Comment: I was looking up the definition of indefinite article and the definition reads like this : "The indefinite article is used when 'the' noun is....." Could you tell me why 'the' was used and if I use 'a' instead then what will be the difference ?